# Unable to load jvm.dll using LoadLibrary

Tags: c++, jvm

One of our customers is having an issue with our application where it is unable to load the jvm.dll.  We install a JRE with our software and so the jvm.dll is the same one that works for all of our other customers.  Here's the code:

```
HMODULE MyApplication::GetJVMDll(char* szJavaHome)
{
    HMODULE hLibrary;
    char szPath[2048];

        strcpy_s(szPath,2048,szJavaHome);   
    #if defined( _WIN64 )   
        strcat_s(szPath, 2048,"\\bin\\msvcrt.dll"); 
    #else
        strcat_s(szPath, 2048,"\\bin\\msvcr71.DLL");    
    #endif

    hLibrary = LoadLibrary (szPath);
    if (!hLibrary) {
            return NULL;
    }
    strcpy_s(szPath,2048,szJavaHome);
    strcat_s(szPath, 2048,"\\bin\\server\\JVM.DLL");

    hLibrary = LoadLibrary (szPath);
    if (hLibrary) {
            return hLibrary;
    }

    printErrorMessage(GetLastError());

    return NULL;
}
```

As I said, the above code works for all our customers except one.  The msvcrt.dll is being loaded successfully, but jvm.dll is not.  The error returned by GetLastError() is 127.  Anyone know why LoadLibrary would be failing for this customer?

Comment: When LoadLibrary() has failed for me, it is because a dependent DLL is missing.  Use dependency walker (google it) to check.

Answer (score 1):

From [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND 127 (0x7F) The specified procedure could not be
>   found.

In this snippet:

```
strcpy_s(szPath,2048,szJavaHome);
```

Could it be possible that `szPath` + `szJavaHome` goes beyond the 2048 limit? In which case the loading of the library would fail.

An other possibility:
Depending on the way you retrieve the `szJavaHome`, and the meaning of that variable; if it is just the `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable, then maybe checking if it contains a trailing slash could be helpful.

Last possibility, check what dependencies this `jvm.dll` have. It may be that one of these transitive dependencies cannot load.